# Is there any way other than using GSEvent to fake touch events on iOS 7 devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitouch

I need to fake the touch events on iOS 7 devices.I've gone through some of the resources available but could not find anything that says about iOS 7.

Below is what i set out to achieve:
    An iOS background code running on iOS 7 device which will listen on a socket, to which client side app will send mouse key presses which are converted into touch/swipe etc. events.

I've gone through this link http://blog.lazerwalker.com/blog/2013/10/16/faking-touch-events-on-ios-for-fun-and-profit as well but here also it is said that GSEvent will fail silently in iOS 7.

Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ControlFreak](https://github.com/n00neimp0rtant/ControlFreak).
So after adding and importing it, you can perform touches

```
- (void)performTouchInView:(UIView *)view
{
    UITouch *touch = [[UITouch alloc] initInView:view];
    UIEvent *eventDown = [[UIEvent alloc] initWithTouch:touch];

    [touch.view touchesBegan:[eventDown allTouches] withEvent:eventDown];

    [touch setPhase:UITouchPhaseEnded];
    UIEvent *eventUp = [[UIEvent alloc] initWithTouch:touch];

    [touch.view touchesEnded:[eventUp allTouches] withEvent:eventUp];
}
```

Also you can specify point for touch

```
UITouch *touch = [[UITouch alloc] initInView:view xcoord:100 ycoord:100];
```

Comment: how to set a touch in specific CGPoint(x,y)?

Comment: so you can also call `UITouch *touch = [[UITouch alloc] initInView:view xcoord:100 ycoord:100];`

Comment: But in this case we must modify the method initinView in UItouchSynthesis ??How we can do it?because I tried and it doesn't work for me on ios7